# C++ Segmentation Fault in code fragment

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I tested my code in Eclipse and everything worked fine - I'm now running the project from a terminal and keep getting a Segmentation Fault. I've narrowed the problem down to this segment:

[This code constructs a distance matrix using a vector of Node pointers.]

```
for(unsigned int j=0;j<numPts;j++) {
     for(unsigned int k=j+1;k<numPts;k++) {
         Node* a = points[j];
         Node* b = points[k];
         double xd = a->GetX()- b->GetX();
         double yd = a->GetY() - b->GetY();

        unsigned int dab = int(round(sqrt(xd*xd + yd*yd)));
        (*distances)[(int)j][(int)k] = dab;
        (*distances)[(int)k][(int)j] = dab;
      }
}
```

How can I fix this segment of code so that I don't get any Segmentation faults?

[Edit] - The line where it is crashing is the `double xd = a->GetX() - b->GetX();` line.

[Edit 2] - This is how I've been creating the vector:

```
std::vector<Node*> myVec;
Node* p1 = new Node(xval, yval);
myVec.push_back(p1);
```

[Edit 3] - This is how I Implemented the Node:

```
#include <utility> 
class Node : public std::pair<double, double> 
{ 
public: 
        Node(double x, double y) : std::pair<double, double>(x,y) 
        {} 

        double GetY() const {return second;} 
        double GetX() const {return first;} 

};
```

---

So I figured out the problem... the pointer at myVec[0] wasn't NULL but it was corrupted in some way. I had "inserted" an element in the beginning of the vector and that was causing all the bugs:

```
std::vector<Node*>::iterator it;
it = myVec.begin();
myVec.insert(it, newNodePtr);
```

Once I removed that, everything worked.

Comment: look in a debugger or with valgrind on which line you reach outside of those arrays or vectors.

Comment: Can we see the declaration of points? and distances?

Comment: Just so you know, you probably have a bug in either case. Eclipse isn't magical, it just may give you a larger memory space so that overrunning array bounds doesn't result in a segfault.

Comment: An actual answer to "how to avoid segfault". 1) Use smart pointers (for your points a and b) or instances, avoid using dumb pointers like the plague. 2) Use vectors instead of new'd arrays (or std::array if you feel really fancy). 3. Follow the rule of 3 (rule of 5 or rule of 0 for c++11).

Comment: @asriraman93 That actually doesn't mean alot. Seg faults are sometimes a little annoying to track down. A seg fault at that line could mean a or b are NULL, a or b have been destroyed (deleted), or (my guess most likly) that you ran over with points[j] or points[k], and the pointer you got back is pointing to garbage.

Comment: I've been storing Nodes in a vector of pointers ( std::vector<Node*> myVector ). I add things to the vector by creating a new Node ptr (Node* p1 = new Node(x, y)) and pushing it to the back. I'm actually not able to access any element in this vector by doing myVector.at(0)->GetX() or anything!!!

Comment: @asriraman93 show us how you create those vectors and the nodes.

Comment: Any reason you are storing pointers to Nodes instead of the Nodes directly?  It will make clean up and assignment a whole lot easier and safer as long as you can construct them and copy them into the container.

Comment: I'm interfacing my code with some libraries I found online which use pointers of Nodes.

Comment: It may or may not help if you showed us where you declared and initialized points as well as the implementation of GetX()

Comment: Yes, time to post class Node to see what it is doing - perhaps the get functions require some setup work to function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that area is indeed the cause of the faults, check:

```
Node* a = points[j];
Node* b = points[k];
```

for `NULL` or bad pointer values before attempting to dereference them,

Also, make sure `distances` is Non-NULL and also a valid pointer in your second assignment and that j and k as 2-dimensional offsets point to the actual `distances` buffer and not beyond it (make sure that `numPts` really is what you mean to use as your buffer endpoint.)

If you cannot `if` them, then at least `assert` them.

**from your edit**

the first part of my post applies - `a` and/or `b` are almost assuredly bad or `NULL` pointers, which is causing your crash.  Look to how you are assigning memory to that array/container/ whatever it is or check it for memory corruptions.

Comment: I ensured that the pointers aren't null so I guess they must be "bad." How do I create the vector of pointers in a better way so that I'm able to access them later?